# self.assertContains fails; Couldn't find *word* in response

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm having difficulty completely rendering the template of `TopicsPage`. It's suppose to render `sub_heading.html` which extends `listing.html` (*both templates reside in the same templates folder*). The test passes the `self.assertTemplateUsed()` assertion.

However an AssertionError is raised at the point of:

`self.assertContains(response, "Looking for more?")`

`AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find 'Looking for more?' in response`

How can I get the `sub_heading.html` content to render for the test to pass when the template is being used already? I put the implementation for GET method as `pass` intentionally just to show how I'm subclassing the View.

test_views.py

```
class TestTopicsPage__002(TestCase):
    '''Verify that a topic and associated information is displayed
    on the main page once the topic is created'''

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        user = User.objects.create_user("TestUser")
        python_tag = Tag.objects.create(name="Python")
        js_tag = Tag.objects.create(name="JavaScript")
        content = {
            'heading': "Test Title",
            'text': "Mock text content",
            'posted': datetime.datetime.now()
        }

        cls.topic = Topic(**content)
        cls.topic.author = user
        cls.topic.save()
        cls.topic.tags.add(python_tag, js_tag)

    def test_topics_main_page_rendered_topics(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse("listing")
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "topics/sub_listing.html")
        self.assertContains(response, "Looking for more?")
```

views.py

```
class AbstractListingPage(TemplateView):

    template_name = "topics/sub_listing.html"

    extra_content = {
        'query_links': ['interesting', 'hot', 'week', 'month']
    }

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['topics'] = Topic.objects.all()
        context['search_form'] = SearchForm()
        context['login_form'] = UserLoginForm
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['login_form'](data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            resolver = resolve(request.path)
            login(request, form.get_user())
            if resolver.namespace:
                url = f"{resolver.namespace}:{resolver.url_name}"
            else:
                url = resolver.url_name
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse(url)
            )
        return self.render_to_response(context)


class TopicsPage(AbstractListingPage):

    def get(self, request):
      pass
```

listing.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
  {% if not topics %}
    <h1 class="topics_placeholder">"Whoops...no topics are being talked about"</h1>
    <h2>Join the community...NOW!</h2>
  {% else %}
    {% for topic in topics %}
      <ul class="topic_stats">
        <li>{{ topic.answers.count }} answers</li>
        <li>{{ topic.likes }} likes</li>
        <li>{{ topic.views }} views</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="topic_wrapper">
        <h1><a href="{% url 'topics:topic' id=topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></h1>
        <ul>
          {% for tag in topic.tags.all %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'topics:tag_listing' tag=tag %}">{{ tag }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <p>{{ topic.posted }}</p>
        <p><a href="{% url 'users:profile' id=topic.author.id %}">{{ topic.author }}</a></P>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
{% block page_branch %}

{% endblock %}
<div class="question-header">
  <button class="flex_item_btn button_widget red" type="button">
    <a href="{% url 'topics:ask' %}">Ask Question</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

sub_listing.html

```
{% extends 'topics/listing.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_branch %}
  <h2>Looking for more? Browse the <a href="{% url 'topics:paginated' %}">complete list of questions</a>
    or <a href="{% url 'topics:tag_listing' %}">popular tags</a></h2>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: listing.html extends index.html.  Does index.html have a block page_branch?  I get the impression that all the content of listing.html should be in block content

Comment: The {% block page_branch %} block is only in listing.html. I'm trying to create two templates that branch off from listing.html. The content of listing.html is suppose to be the same between sub_listing.html and an other template. Yet those two templates also have content that are unique upon themselves once it reaches {% block page_branch %}.

Comment: I don't think it will ever reach {% block page_branch %}, because it's not a block in the highest level template, nor is it contained in a block in the highest level template.  Try moving {% endblock content %} to the very bottom?

Comment: That got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The content at the bottom of listing.html is orphaned, not existing inside a block present in the parent template.

```
{% block page_branch %}

{% endblock %}
<div class="question-header">
  <button class="flex_item_btn button_widget red" type="button">
    <a href="{% url 'topics:ask' %}">Ask Question</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Since listing.html extends index.html, it can only override blocks that exist in index.html.  The above content must be put inside {% block content %} to be rendered at all.  Then sub_listing.html's use of {% block page_branch %} will be rendered.